# Is there something like Hibernate's AliasToBeanResultTransformer for JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

I'm looking for a JPA way to inject the result of a query into a [Java Bean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions) like Hibernate's [`AliasToBeanResultTransformer`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/AliasToBeanResultTransformer.html):

> Result transformer that allows to transform a result to a user specified class which will be populated via setter methods or fields matching the alias names.
>
> ```
> List resultWithAliasedBean = s.createCriteria(Enrolment.class)
>                    .createAlias("student", "st")
>                    .createAlias("course", "co")
>                    .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
>                        .add( Projections.property("co.description"), "courseDescription" )
>                    )
>                    .setResultTransformer( new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(StudentDTO.class) )
>                    .list();
>
> StudentDTO dto = (StudentDTO)resultWithAliasedBean.get(0);
> ```

I found JPA's [CriteriaQuery#multiselect](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#multiselect(javax.persistence.criteria.Selection...)) with a user-defined class, but it needs a non default constructor:

> - If the type of the criteria query is CriteriaQuery for some user-defined class X (i.e., a criteria query object created by passing a X class argument to the createQuery method), the arguments to the multiselect method will be passed to the X constructor and an instance of type X will be returned for each row.

I found JPA's [CriteriaBuilder#construct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#construct-java.lang.Class-javax.persistence.criteria.Selection...-), but it needs also a non default constructor:

> Create a selection item corresponding to a constructor. This method is used to specify a constructor that will be applied to the results of the query execution.

Is there another way without a non default constructor?